# delete nested class objects correctly?

Tags: c++

My code is like following, basically I am using some external library and embed some class objects from this library to myClass, then do things with OBJ,

```
#include  "extern_lib.h" //some library

class myClass
{
public:
extern_class *obj1;
extern_class *obj2;
double arr[3];
};

int main()
{

myClass *OBJ= new myClass();

OBJ->obj1 = new extern_class(arg1...);
OBJ->obj2 = new extern_class(arg2...);

//do something like

OBJ->obj1->extern_fun1(arg1...);
OBJ->obj2->extern_fun2(arg2...);

//delete 
delete OBJ;

return 0;
}
```

I would like to know,

1- in order to free all the objects, is it enough to delete OBJ?

2- is there better ways to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to free all the objects, is it enough to delete OBJ?

No, this will produce a resource leak as the (default) destructor of `myClass` doesn't care about deleting the pointer members.

> Is there better ways to write this code?

Yes, use smart pointers.  For example:

```
class myClass
{
public:
  std::unique_ptr<extern_class> obj1;
  std::unique_ptr<extern_class> obj2;
  double arr[3];
};
```

In general, try to make resources *owned* by classes.  That is, allocate them in the constructor and deallocate them in the destructor.  The standard library's smart pointers will already do that job for you.  Avoid managing more than one resource inside a single class.

By the way: If your example is not contrived and you are really not using polymorphism at all, then just get rid of all those `new`s and simply use variables with automatic storage duration.  C++ is not Java.

**Update:** Here is (one way of) how to get rid of `new` if polymorphism is not needed:

```
class myClass
{
public:
  extern_class obj1;
  extern_class obj2;
  double arr[3];

  myClass(type arg1a, ..., type arg2a, ...) : obj1(arg1a, ...), obj2(arg2a, ...)
  //                                          ^^^^ member initializer list ^^^^
  {
  }
};
```

The key is to create the member objects as part of the process of creating `myClass` by using a so-called *member initializer list*.  If you are programming C++11, prefer writing `obj1 {arg1a, ...}, obj2 {arg2a, ...}` for consistency.  (The old syntax still works equally well, however.)

Likewise in your `main` function:

```
int
main()
{
  myClass mc(arg1a, ..., arg2a, ...);  // (1)
  mc.obj1.extern_func(...);
  mc.obj2.extern_func(...);
  return 0;  // (2)
}
```

At line (1), we create an instance of `myClass` on the stack using our new constructor that will create the members `obj1` and `obj2` correctly.  The compiler-generated default constructor of `myClass` will correctly destruct `mc.obj1` and `mc.obj2` as `mc` goes out of scope on line (2).  Again, in C++11 line (1) can be written more cleanly as `myClass mc {arg1a, ..., arg2a, ...};`.

Comment: sorry i'am new to c++, but if i don't use "new", with "extern_class  obj1;" with "OBJ->obj1 =  extern_class(arg1...);" it doesn't work, basically i need to initialise obj1 first according to arg1. perhaps i'am wrong...

Comment: Not sure what you could have get wrong.  My code example compiles if you provide appropriate declarations of `extern_class` and `extern_func` (and rename `type` and remove the ellipsis, of course).  Maybe ask a new question?

Comment: one last thing, "The compiler-generated default constructor of myClass will correctly destruct mc.obj1 and mc.obj2 as mc goes out of scope ", how does it work, through what mechanism?

Comment: Through the property of C++ that as a variable with automatic storage duration (ie stack allocated) goes out of scope, its destructor will be called.  Members of objects go out of scope as their containing object is destructed.  Once you move from automatic storage to the free store (ie heap allocated, via using `new`) you'll have to do that work yourself as there is no “scope” on the heap.  If you don't define a destructor for a class, the compiler will create a default one – and often times, this one is just fine.

Answer (score 3):

1. No, it is not enough. You have to call `delete` for every `new` you place in your code explicitely.
2. Use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or better, use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). To clarify that: smart pointers and RAII are not even only *better ways* of doing so, they are *the* ways of doing it correctly in modern C++.

Here's an adequate example with **RAII**:

```
#include "extern_lib.h"

class myClass
{
public: // note that public members are possibly bad design (depending on your situation)
    extern_class obj1;
    extern_class obj2;
    double arr[3];
};

int main()
{
    myClass foo;
    foo.obj1.extern_fun(arg1...);
    foo.obj2.extern_fun(arg2...);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that it's not possible to use RAII in every situation. If you run into such, use smart pointers as stated:

```
#include "extern_lib.h"

class myClass
{
public: // note that public members are possibly bad design (depending on your situation)
    std::unique_ptr<extern_class> obj1;
    std::unique_ptr<extern_class> obj2;
    double arr[3];
};

int main()
{
    myClass foo;
    foo.obj1 = std::unique_ptr<extern_class>(new extern_class(arg1...));
    foo.obj2 = std::unique_ptr<extern_class>(new extern_class(arg2...));

    foo.obj1->extern_fun(arg1...);
    foo.obj2->extern_fun(arg2...);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for smart pointers and RAII, can you give some brief illustration based on my example?

Comment: I have to say that i use"OBJ->obj1 = new extern_class(arg1...)" because obj1 needs to be initialised according to some arguments in the main function, so the RAII example you showed doesn't fit?

Comment: The RAII solution is indeed possible, but with a few caveats. You would have to pass all arguments you want to pass to ``obj1`` and ``obj2`` to the ``myClass`` first and then initialize both objects using ``initialization lists``. In this specific situatiuon, it really sounds better for me to use the smart pointer approach since it's not a good practice to copy the same parameters to another, overlying function (in this case the constructor). Maybe you want to tell what you want to achieve, not how. Then we can answer your question, not your approach.

Comment: thanks! the reason i did this is simple, there's some routine which allows me to use only one argument as the I/O interface, so I have to pack several class objects together, and they have to be initialised at some points in the main fun.